# Why does my page fall into the infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, random, html-table, infinite-loop, innerhtml

```
function randomNumber(){
    var value;
    var flag = false;
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    do{
        value = Math.round(Math.random() * (26 - 1) + 1);
        for(var t = 0; t < tds.length; t++){
            if(tds[t].innerHTML == value)
                flag = true;
        }
        if(!flag){
            return value;
        }
    }while(flag == true)
}
```

This function returns a random number for innerHTML of a new td. In case there are other tds with the same number as this code generates, the loop starts once again. If the generated number is unique, I add it to the innerHTML of a new td. But I can't even load the page since I run into an infinite loop, but no matter how hard I tried, I couldn't notice the problem in logic of this code.

Comment: What is the condition to set `flag` as false ?

Comment: Q: Why does my page fall into the infinite loop?  A: Probably because "value" apparently always equals  "tds[t].innerHTML", and flag never remains "false". SUGGESTION: Step through the code in a debugger (e.g. Chrome Developer Tools) and look at "value" as you iterate through the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as your loop find the case where `tds[t].innerHTML == value` it sets `flag` to `true` - at this point you can never end the loop because nowhere do you check for a case where you can set `flag` to `false`, so your loop condition will *always* be true.

Here's a similar example that illustrated this with an array. You can see that sometimes it adds numbers to the array (in the case where it finds a new value) but other times the loop hits 5000 iterations an exits (because it never finds a new value), in which case it adds `undefined` to the array, since the function hasn't returned anything.

```js
const arr = []
function randomNumber(){
    var value;
    var flag = false;
    var tds = arr
    var iterations = 0

    do {
        value = Math.round(Math.random() * (26 - 1) + 1);
        for(var t = 0; t < tds.length; t++){
            if(tds.includes(value))
                flag = true;
        }
        if(!flag){
            return value;
        }
        iterations += 1
        console.log(iterations)
    } while(flag == true && iterations < 5000)
}

for (let i = 0;i<20;i+=1) {
  arr.push(randomNumber())
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: You have `arr` accessed from in and out of the function - its not really great to have global variables - you really shouldnt write code like that. Also - why you iterate 5000 times, if for example all 26 id's are already used? You will loose more than 4800 iterations, when you could just check if your function has even slight chance of returning anything it should

Comment: Points noted - this is an example meant to illustrate the principles & show how the iterations kept going, not an implementation of a best-practice solution.

Comment: Still if you got that in his code, and that code went into production - it would be very bad

Answer (score 1):

The moment your function at least once set the `flag` to true, its over - it never sets it to false again.  To fix it i added one line of code.

```js
function randomNumber(){
    var value;
    var flag = false;
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    do {
        flag = false; // this line i added
        value = Math.round(Math.random() * (26 - 1) + 1);
        for(var t = 0; t < tds.length; t++){
            if(tds[t].innerHTML == value)
                flag = true;
        }
        if(!flag){
            return value;
        }
    }while(flag == true)
}
```

I will also write a bit more efficient code for you

```
function randomNumber(){
    var value;
    var found = false;
    var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    var existingIds = [];
    tds.forEach(td => existingIds.push(td.innerHHML)); // fill up the ids
    do {
        value = Math.round(Math.random() * (26 - 1) + 1); // this line would make problems (comment below)
        if (existingIds.indexOf(value) === -1) found = true; // check if value can be found in existing ids and if found - set dount to true (you can also return from here, but i would rather user break (if there was more code after this line, than use retur in the middle of any loop;
    } while(found === false)

    return value;
}
```

Comment for line with random:

- random() returns number from 0 to 1
- as you wrote it - that value would be random number between 1 and 26 (only this values).
- if all of the values are already used then our loop will be not ending (we could never find value between 1 and 26 that is not used, when all values from 1 to 26 are already used.

What can be done

- You can add some counter (as @Ben did) and exit the loop in that case.
- Or you can raise the number 26 to much higher
- You can use consecutive numbers (get all, take the max one, add 1 and return this as new number)

You can of course find some other ways to counter that

Comment: Wow, I'm just irritated a bit that everything is that easy. I've spent about 30 mins on this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem it happens when you just start you adventure with programming/language

Comment: @Дмитрий Уткин - Please familiarize yourself with a good debugger, and get in the habit of stepping through your code.